# Background images not working in Outlook Email

Tags: email-templates

[image: screen short]

when i send a same email to Gmail and outLook 
its work perfectly on Gmail but in outLook its not showing background-image of div

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook supports background images and it's using VML. VML (vector markup language) is native to outlook. Below is the code you can use:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:[WIDTH]px;height:[HEIGHT]px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="[IMAGE PATH]" color="#[FALLBACK COLOR]" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]--> 
[HTML CONTENT HERE]
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->]]>
```

All you need to do is change the height and width of the `VML`, add in the image path and you are good to go. Be sure to place this inside a table with a specific width or you will have tiled images.

Cheers